# Weak and ephemeral Diffie-Hellman key on CISCO PRIME

Tags: cisco, google-chrome

Can't login on Cisco Prime web interface due to this error on chrome. How to solve?

Comment: You call Cisco TAC and find out which update you forgot to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cisco has yet to release a firmware update for any of the RV0XX routers. Until this happens, you'll need to modify Firefox to gain access.

In the address bar, type `about: config`

Then search for "ssl3". Set the following values to false:

```
security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_128_sha

security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_256_sha
```

Comment: Even this is just a work around, is the most simple "solution" at the moment without upgrading.
It works.